# How to understand NavLinkProps Interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

In the Interface for *NavLinkProps* (React Router v6) as below, I believe that's written in Typescript, but when I checked the Typescript documentation for "Interface", I couldn't see what it means to have a Union Operator "|" **after** "children:" and **before** "React.ReactNode", as in:

```
 children:
    | React.ReactNode
    | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
```

Full Interface is here . . .

```
export interface NavLinkProps
  extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style" | "children"> {
  children:
    | React.ReactNode
    | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  className?: string | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => string | undefined);
  end?: boolean;
  style?:
    | React.CSSProperties
    | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.CSSProperties);
}
```

All the examples in the TypeScript documentation only had the Union Operator "|" ** after** the first type (as in:

```
interface Foo {
  myType: string | number;
}
```

How is that different from?:

```
interface Foo {
  myType: | string | number;
}
```

Comment: It's no different. They just allow both syntaxes because the extra `|` is aesthetically pleasing when the type is spread on multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not different - a leading operator is just allowed to make multi-line types more readable.

I dug into the TypeScript sources; this was implemented in [#12386](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12386), so it appeared in TS v2.1.4. Parsing of the leading operator was further improved in [#31265](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31265).

Consider

```
type X = 
  | foo
  | bar
  | quux
  | spam
  | eggs;
```

vs

```
type X = 
  foo
  | bar
  | quux
  | spam
  | eggs;
```

which makes it seem that `foo` is somehow special.